# Is there a way to have the unwrapping function not rearrange islands?

Tags: uv

I have a character I want to unwrap. I marked my seams and when I hit "unwrap" all islands are  auto-rearranged.

This is a great function but I need to overlap mirrored unwraps and the different scale and rotation of each island makes this difficult. Overlapping results not perfect as I would like. Is there a way to avoid this auto arrangement?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes - to some extent, you can pin UV's to control the placement of each island.
To control the scale and placement you only have to pin 2 uvs on the island, to control the overall shape better you may want to pin 4 or more.

See docs on live-unwrap and pinning, older [wiki docs](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.4/Books/Essential_Blender/10.2.UV_Unwrapping_and_Painting%3a_Tools#Pinning_and_Live_Unwrap_Transform) but still valid